# Cosmological metric with off-diagonal terms?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, metric-tensor

In the context of Cosmology models, What are examples of metrics with off-diagonal terms?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Any metric tensor can via a coordinate transformation acquire off-diagonal terms. Besides this looks like a list question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the [Bianchi metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_classification#Cosmological_application) have off-diagonal terms. Examples are the [Taub metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taub-NUT_vacuum) and the [Mixmaster metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixmaster_universe). For more information on the Bianchi models, see [Collins & Hawking (1973)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1973MNRAS.162..307C).

Another example is the [Gödel metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric).

You may also find this paper useful: http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0043